# Waiting for process until it terminate to run an other

Tags: batch-file

I have an executable file that generate me reports in the current folder, I want that after generating the report to move it to another folder :

```
start /WAIT /B "" "C:\Generator.exe"
for /R "C:\" %%f in (*.xlsx) do copy  "%%f" "C:\ABC"
Del /Q "C:\*.xlsx"
```

the problem is that The second and third lines in the batch files run before the first line terminate (it show me a message that the .xlsx file does not exist which is quite normal becaus the .exe is still running)

Comment: What happens if you just call Generator.exe?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
C:\Generator.exe
for /R "C:\" %%f in (*.xlsx) do copy  "%%~f" "C:\ABC"
Del /Q "C:\*.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c:\generator.exe
:sleeping
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq generator.exe" 
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto sleeping
for /R "C:\" %%f in (*.xlsx) do copy  "%%f" "C:\ABC"
Del /Q "C:\*.xlsx"
exit
```

There is a sleeping till generator.exe stops and then proceeds to next lines in your code ... the errorlevel checks if the process is running (status = 0) so till the time the errorlevel becomes 1 the loop goes on.

Sid

Comment: :sleeping is not recognized as an internal or external command